# "return outside function" error

Tags: python, if-statement, return

After some research, I cannot find out why I'm getting the specified error (`SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`) in this codeacademy exercise.

```
name=input(" input name ")
print("welcome, {}".format (name))

class player():

    def __init__(self, atk, hp,):
        self.atk=atk
        self.hp=hp

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, {}".format (self.atk, self.hp)

input("Time for a questionnaire to define your stats")
input("press enter to continue....")
print("in an intense battle when both you and your enemy are on the edge of consciousness and you have a chance to flee do you finish off the opponent taking a chance on being struck down or do you flee with your life?")
statq1=input("fight or flee")
if statq1 == "fight":
    return 5+self
elif statq1 == "flee":
    return 5+hp
```

Comment: It's telling you the `return` is outside the function because it _is_ (and that's bad). I recommend brushing up on indentation as well as on the specific meaning of the `return` statement.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? The code you gave in your question is not at all usable.

Comment: how would I fix this then?

Comment: By rereading the instructional materials provided by CodeAcademy. If you find those materials insufficient, the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) is a great resource.

Comment: @ErRds is this your entire code?

Comment: It's the beginning, So I guess yeah

Answer (score 3):

`return` must be inside a function. Right now that code is at the base of the script, so you either way to save `5+self` to variable to use later, or print it to the screen it seems.

To make it into a function:

```
def start():
    input("Time for a questionnaire to define your stats")
    input("press enter to continue....")
    print("in an intense battle when both you and your enemy are on the edge of consciousness and you have a chance to flee do you finish off the opponent taking a chance on being struck down or do you flee with your life?")
    statq1=input("fight or flee")
    if statq1 == "fight":
        return 5+self
    elif statq1 == "flee":
        return 5+hp

print(start())
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot

Comment: @ErRds `return` roughly means something like "exit a function and take a value back with you." If you put `return` in the outer scope, with no function, where's it supposed to go? Confused? So is Python. Hence, the error. :)

Comment: @CasualDemon
Thanks a ton.

Think that gave me more clarity into why I kept getting the types of return errors.